# Enable default hyphenation for body of prefixed word

Tags: hyphenation

Suppose the word `automorphism` has correct hyphenation rules, but `(anti)automorphism` does not (because it contains non letters).
Since `(anti-)` and similar prefixes are common, I’ve written a macro

```
\newcommand{\prefixparen}[1]{(#1\discretionary{-)}{}{)}}
```

to achieve my desired hyphenation behaviour at parenthetical boundaries:

```
│(anti)automorphism (anti-)│       % good
│automorphism (anti)automor│phism  % sad
```

However, note that `\prefixparen{anti}automorphism` does not hyphenate within the main word, as shown in the second line.

I tried putting a zero-width space at the end of the macro to make the root its own word:

```
\newcommand{\prefixparen}[1]{(#1\discretionary{-)}{}{)}~\!}
                                               % space ^ ^ 'backspace'
```

...but `TeX` still seems to notice it and doesn't attempt hyphenation.
How can I get the following desired behaviour?

```
│(anti)automorphism (anti-)│
│automorphism   (anti)auto-│ % uses already-learned hyphenation rules
│morphism ...              │
```

Comment: `~\!` is not zero width! You want `\hspace{0pt}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}` in order to

1. make the discretionary work and
2. allow hyphenation in the following word.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\prefixparens}[1]{%
  (#1% the item with the open parenthesis
  \discretionary{-)}{}{)}% a discretionary
  \nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}% allow hyphenation in the following
}

\begin{document}

\prefixparens{anti}automorphism

\parbox[t]{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}%
  \prefixparens{anti}automorphism
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`TeX` will not hyphenate `~\!automorphism` because of the presence of the non-letter `\!` in the “word” `\!automorphism`.
However, it will work with `\!~automorphism` because `~` separates words.
Thus:

```
\newcommand{\prefixparen}[1]{(#1\discretionary{-)}{}{)}\!~}
```

works exactly as desired.

Comment: sorry this is the wrong answer `\!~` may add a variable amount of space, use `\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}`

Comment: the spaces added are font dependent but with computer modern `~` adds `3.33333pt plus 1.66666pt minus 1.11111pt` and `\!` adds `-1.66672pt`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I was hoping someone would address that!
I’ll accept that comment as an answer if you post it as such. (Can’t accept my own answer if I edit it… yet)

Comment: that's OK, you can accept egreg's: he needs the points